# What kind of species is this?

Tags: species-identification

Does anyone know what this is? It is seen in France. It looks like it has eight legs and is about 8-10 cm long.

[image: some kind of insect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a longhorn beetle, family Cerambycidae. Two of the "eight legs" are antennae. It looks a lot like the one pictured here: https://hiveminer.com/Tags/cerambycidae%2Cfrance